# Python, requests failed to decode the data?

Tags: python, python-requests

I was wondering what causes the below error is it the site the data is being sent to or an issue with the script?

I'm sending the following POST request:

```
import requests 

session = requests.session() 
url = "private url" 
headers = {"Content-Type": "Application/json"} 
session.headers.update(headers) 
payload = {"test": "test", "quantity": 1} 
output = session.post(url, data=payload) 
print(output.text)
```

Output:

> `{"_v":"14.6","fault":{"type":"InvalidMessageException","message":"An error occurred while decoding the request, the body was 'test=test&quantity=1'."}`

Comment: without any context how can we help? [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: just want to know what the error means @MikeTung

Comment: `An error occurred while decoding the request, the body was 'test=test&quantity=1'` seems pretty coherent

Comment: @MikeTung Is this caused by the site or my script?

Comment: Your script.  Could you post the code that you're using to make the request here?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh this is my script

Comment: import requests

session = requests.session()
url = "private url"

headers={
    "Content-Type": "Application/Json"
}

session.headers.update(headers)

payload ={
  "test": "test",
  "quantity": 1
}

output = session.post(url, data=payload)

print(output.text)

Comment: It wont let me format

Comment: so put it into the question

Comment: @IvanVinogradov Done still formatted really weirdly by stack

Comment: If it's a json request, you may need `output = session.post(url, json=payload)` to assist in formatting. The `json` kwarg allows requests to properly format your request body, since that's not explicitly tied to the header

Comment: @C.Nivs Thanks! that fixed it